# Assembly to C assistance

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I have an assignment where I need to convert assembly to C. The assembly is x86. I annotated the assembly and started filling in the blanks in the C but I'm a little lost on a couple things, can someone assist? Please explain don't just give the answer I'm trying to learn.

Assembly:

```
x at %ebp+8, n at %ebp+12

1 movl 8(%ebp), %esi  //store x in esi
2 movl 12(%ebp), %ebx //store n in ebx
3 movl $-1, %edi      //result in edi
4 movl $1, %edx       //i of loop in edx
5 .L2:
6 movl %edx, %eax     //move edx to eax
7 andl %esi, %eax     //sum += 1 ...? i think
8 xorl %eax, %edi     //results = results ^ (i & x)
9 movl %ebx, %ecx     //store n in ecx
10 sall %cl, %edx     //shift edx by %cl (low byte of ecx)
11 testl %edx, %edx   //check if zeroed out
12 jne .L2            //jump to .L2 if flag
13 movl %edi, %eax    //move result to eax
```

C code:

```
int loop(int x, int n) {
  int result = _______;
  int mask;
  for (mask = 1; mask != 0; mask = ______) {
     result ^= mask & x;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I started out like this:

```
movl 8(%ebp), %esi  ;; esi :=  x
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx ;; ebx :=  n
movl $-1, %edi      ;; edi := -1
movl $1, %edx       ;; edx :=  1
.L2:
movl %edx, %eax     ;; eax := edx
andl %esi, %eax     ;; eax &= esi (:= x) 
xorl %eax, %edi     ;; edi ^= eax
movl %ebx, %ecx     ;; ecx := ebx (:= n)
sall %cl, %edx      ;; edx <<= ecx & 0x000000FF
testl %edx, %edx    ;; set flags with edx & edx
jne .L2             ;; loop if not ZF
movl %edi, %eax     ;; eax := edi
```

and progressed to this through straight up translation, cutting as few corners as I could manage:

```
int x, n, foo = -1, bar = 1;

do {
    int baz = bar;
    baz &= x;
    foo ^= baz;

    int qux = n;
    bar <<= qux & 0xFF;
} while (bar);

// now do something with foo
```

and then reached this by removing unnecessary temp variables, changing to a friendlier form of loop, and adding the function body and return statement:

```
int func(int x, int n) {
    int result = -1;

    for (int mask = 1; mask; mask <<= n) {
        result ^= (mask & x);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note here that I have dropped masking out all bar the lower byte of `n` in the left shift. After some discussion in the comments, I've settled on that and adding an explanation.
We can use `sal` in one of two ways:

1. Immediate, e.g. `sall $2, %edx ;; left shift EDX by 2`
2. Shift via CL, e.g. `sall %cl, %edx ;; left shift EDX by the lower byte of ECX`

Since shifting by the number of bits in an integer type or more is [undefined behaviour](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) (and one byte is more than sufficient to represent well defined shifts on a 32-bit number), the compiler isn't obliged to deal with it in a useful way, so anything being compiled to a shift via CL doesn't need to bother explicitly masking. Thus there's no need to show an explicit mask in the C 'translation', but since this is an assignment I heartily recommend actually explaining your choice either way.

(Credit to [Peter Huene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530189/peter-huene) for bringing this up in the comments.)

You can also generate x86 assembly from your resulting C code to see what you get. Don't expect to get the exact same thing you started with, instead use it as a way to learn. For instance you can check `<< n` is compiled to in our loop. Something like `clang -O0 -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=att filename.c` will do the trick.

I'm not quite sure what you want explained as you had most stuff sorted already (except for `movl $-1, %edi` initialising result to `-1` and `andl %esi, %eax` not being addition)

Comment: I think the expression `n & 0xFF` is misleading here, since there is no corresponding assembly to map it too, despite being semantically correct (a simple cast would probably make more sense).  The `sal` instruction only has two representations: an immediate form and shifting via `cl` (fun factoid: Intel processors also mask `cl` to five bits for the `sal` instruction).  Combine this with the fact that overflowing the shift is undefined (i.e. n >= 32) and the compiler knows it doesn't even need to mask the least significant byte.

Comment: I hemmed and hawed quite a bit before expressing it that way, and I do agree with you, _but_ the asker said this was an assignment so I chose to show in the C code that only the lower byte is used for the shift. I'm now contemplating adding some detail re. all this to the answer, which in retrospect is what I should have done in the first place.

Why do you think a cast would be clearer? I think that's arguably worse because (in C99) `int` to `signed char` casting is implementation defined behaviour in the case of an overflow...

Comment: Btw, Intels masking `cl` to five bits for `sal` is cute - thanks for the tip, although I hope it's not actually a factoid (oft-repeated piece of unreliable information).

Comment: I said it that way simply for the alliteration :)

Comment: Its common for processors with single-cycle shifts (shift count in a register) to mask off just the appropriate number of bits and ignore the high order bits.  Sparc, MIPS, ARM, and alpha all work that way as well as newer x86.  Its undefined in C because for older machines with only fixed shifts, the compiler would create a loop for a variable shift.  Some old microcoded machines also used a microcode loop for such shifts -- the original 8086 worked this way, so Iskar's translation is accurate for that (ignoring the fact that it was only 16 bit)